# convert decimal(19,4) to string format

Tags: c#, sql

I have a 3 column which are in this format but I have a client requirment which is in below format . I got everything sorted out but stuck with total amount.

```
pcn charge              100
 court fee                15
 solictors costs          00
 total amount             115

Requirment 

PCN charge -     7 (100) = 0010000
court fee  -     5  (15) = 01500
solictors cost - 5  (0)  = 00000
total amount -   8   (115)= 00011500 ( I am not getting this value i get 00000115.)
```

This is my query :

```
"RIGHT('00'+CAST(CAST(bat.PCN_Charge* 100.00 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),7) as CLAIMAMT," +
"RIGHT('0'+CAST(CAST([CFee] * 100 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),5) as CFEE," +
"RIGHT('00000'+CAST(CAST([Solictors Fees]  AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),5)," +
"RIGHT('00000'+CAST(CAST(bat.PCN_Charge + [CFee] AS INT) AS VARCHAR(5)),8) as TotalAMT " +
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to left pad numbers in SQL Server is to add a big integer and take the right most columns.  Here is what I mean:

```
select right(100000000 + CAST(bat.PCN_Charge * 100.00 AS INT), 7),
       right(100000000 + CAST([CFee] * 100 AS INT), 5),
       right(100000000 + CAST([Solictors Fees]  AS INT), 5),
       right(100000000 + CAST(bat.PCN_Charge*100 + [CFee]*100 AS INT), 8)
```

Note that I added the `*100` to the total.  I think that is what is missing from your code as well.